# Убрать фон у textEdit в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyside2, qss

Разрабатываю приложение, есть поле с текстом в `QTextEdit`. Однако мне не нужен фон в нем. Порылся в документации, но ничего рабочего, увы, не нашел.

[image: текст с фоном вокруг него]

Делал через `Qt Designer`, вот код переведенного `.ui` в `.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

################################################################################
## Form generated from reading UI file 'main.ui'
##
## Created by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 5.14.2
##
## WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
################################################################################


from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject,
    QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter,
    QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(711, 481)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.greeting = QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.greeting.setObjectName(u"greeting")
        self.greeting.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 341, 461))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.greeting.setFont(font)
        self.greeting.setReadOnly(True)
        self.greeting.setBackgroundVisible(False)
        self.greeting.setCenterOnScroll(False)
        self.date = QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.date.setObjectName(u"date")
        self.date.setGeometry(QRect(370, 10, 331, 41))
        self.date.setFont(font)
        self.date.setReadOnly(True)
        self.date.setBackgroundVisible(False)
        self.temp = QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.temp.setObjectName(u"plainTextEdit")
        self.temp.setGeometry(QRect(540, 340, 161, 95))
        font1 = QFont()
        font1.setPointSize(50)
        self.temp.setFont(font1)
        self.temp.setReadOnly(True)
        self.temp.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.calendarWidget = QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName(u"calendarWidget")
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QRect(370, 70, 331, 221))
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setNavigationBarVisible(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0414\u043e\u0431\u0440\u043e\u0435 \u0443\u0442\u0440\u043e", None))
        self.greeting.setPlainText("")
        self.greeting.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Error", None))
        self.date.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Error", None))
        self.temp.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Text", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пример, который у вас есть.

Comment: Опубликовал код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте импорты и попробуйте:

```
'''
from PySide2.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QMetaObject,
    QObject, QPoint, QRect, QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont,
    QFontDatabase, QIcon, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPalette, QPainter,
    QPixmap, QRadialGradient)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
'''

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(711, 481)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.greeting = QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.greeting.setObjectName(u"greeting")
        self.greeting.setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 341, 461))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.greeting.setFont(font)
        self.greeting.setReadOnly(True)
        self.greeting.setBackgroundVisible(False)
        self.greeting.setCenterOnScroll(False)
        self.date = QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.date.setObjectName(u"date")
        self.date.setGeometry(QRect(370, 10, 331, 41))
        self.date.setFont(font)
        self.date.setReadOnly(True)
        self.date.setBackgroundVisible(False)
        self.temp = QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.temp.setObjectName(u"plainTextEdit")
        self.temp.setGeometry(QRect(540, 340, 161, 95))
        font1 = QFont()
        font1.setPointSize(50)
        self.temp.setFont(font1)
        self.temp.setReadOnly(True)
        self.temp.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.calendarWidget = QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName(u"calendarWidget")
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QRect(370, 70, 331, 221))
        self.calendarWidget.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.calendarWidget.setNavigationBarVisible(True)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(False)
        self.calendarWidget.setDateEditEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0414\u043e\u0431\u0440\u043e\u0435 \u0443\u0442\u0440\u043e", None))
        self.greeting.setPlainText("")
        self.greeting.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Error", None))
        self.date.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Error", None))
        self.temp.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Text", None))
    # retranslateUi


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self) 

        self.temp.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f0f0f0; border: none')    # <<<-----<


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!